.editorconfig file does not open in nice VS editor
My solution has two different .editorconfig files in two different locations.  On one of them when I double click it to open, it just opens as a straight text file.  But the second one opens up in this nice editor UI that breaks down the options by category, gives me checkboxes, etc.
What file/setting in VS controls which file is opened in which editor, given that they both have exactly the same name?
(BTW: I'm guessing it is wrong that I have two such files and I'm trying to figure out why that is and to hopefully be able to get rid of one of them.  But for now I just want to know what controls which editor is used for two files).

Probably an extension, example

Regarding how the .editorconfig file is opened, it varies depending on the settings of the project or solution where the file is located. Generally, if the .editorconfig file is associated with the EditorConfig plugin for VS, it will be opened in the editor UI with classification options and checkboxes. If it is not associated, it may be opened in plain text.
You can refer to the content in this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022
In addition, if you want to specify a specific editor for the .editorconfig file, please find it in VS: Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension, where you can set it.
